# Is it okay to use template types from the enclosing function within lambdas in C++11?

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, lambda

So I currently have some code similar to this:

(Note: not actual code, just pared down from a somewhat long and complex method for brevity.)

```
template<typename ArgT0, typename ArgT1, typename FuncT>
static void addMethod( const std::string& name, FuncT func )
{
   Method script_func = [&]( const Arguments& args ) -> Value
   {
      func(UnsafeAnyCast<ArgT0>(args[0]),UnsafeAnyCast<ArgT1>(args[1]));
      return Value::Undefined();
   }

   _prototype->Set( name, script_func );
}
```

It works fine in Visual Studio 2010, but I know that is far from any guarantee that it is standard compliant C++. Is there anything wrong with this as far as using the template arguments inside the lambda?

Comment: It shouldn't really be relevant to the question, but Arguments is a container class for arguments passed via a function call in an embedded scripting language. My question is whether it's standard compliant to use the ArgT0 and ArgT1 template types within the lambda.

Comment: I understand the question. Since Arguments is not seen anywhere in the function, I asked about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is standard compliant: a lambda expression has access to all the visible names in its enclosing scope, it's only variables that you need to capture

**5.1.2 Lambda expressions [expr.prim.lambda]**

> 9 A lambda-expression whose smallest enclosing scope is a block scope
>   (3.3.3) is a local lambda expression; any other lambda-expression
>   shall not have a capture-list in its lambda-introducer. The reaching
>   scope of a local lambda expression is the set of enclosing scopes up
>   to and including the innermost enclosing function and its parameters